# Perl: best way to pass array of hash to a sub

Tags: arrays, perl

My class looks like the below:

```
package CSVKeepCols;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text;
my $del;
my @cols;
my $output = '';

sub load {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub input {
    my $class = shift;
    $text = shift;
    return $class;
}

sub setOpts {
    my ($class, $opts) = @_;
    $del  = $opts->{'delimeter'};
    @cols = $opts->{'columns'};
}

sub process {
    my @lines = split /\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n/, $text;
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => $del });

    foreach (@lines) {
        die('Invalid CSV data') if !$csv->parse($_);
        $output .= __filterFields($csv->fields()) . "\n";
    }
}

sub output {
    return $output;
}

sub __filterFields {
    my @fields = @_;
    my $line = '';

    foreach (@cols) {
        $line .= ',' if $line;
        $line .= $fields[$_];
    }

    return $line;
}

1;
```

I am using this class from my code like this:

```
$parser = load CSVKeepCols();
$parser->input($out);
$parser->setOpts({'delimeter' => ',', 'columns' => [1,2]});
$parser->process();
$out = $parser->output();
```

I am expecting, the setOpts subroutine will take the hash `{'delimeter' => ',', 'columns' => [1,2]}` and from there it will set the value of `$del`to `,` and `@cols` to `(1,2)` so that I can loop through the `@cols` array.

However, when I try to loop through `@cols` in the `__filterFields` subroutine I get error

`Use of reference "ARRAY(0x22e32e0)" as array index at CSVKeepCols.pm line 52.`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't `[1,2]` an arrayref, not an array; shouldn't you store it in `my $cols`. then dereference (like `foreach (@$cols)`)?

Comment: If all your variables are class variables anyway, why instantiate an object at all?

Comment: @raina77ow you are right, [1,2] is a array reference. I didnt know that. It works if I store the dereferenced value like `@cols = @{$opts->{'columns'}};`. However, how can I pass array and make it work? like I tried passing like `$parser->setOpts({'delimeter' => ',', 'columns' => (1,2)});` and it turns out only the first value of the array is being stored in the `@cols` array

Comment: When storing in a hash, which is a (associative) list, you have to store a list of values as an arrayref if you want to retrieve it from the columns key, as one key cannot point to many values. You could alternatively pass an array as parameters into the setOpts method.

Comment: `bless $self` should be `bless $self, $class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In setOpts, you set `@cols = $opts->{columns};`

`$opts->{columns}` contains a reference to an array ( [1,2] ).

So in __filterFields:

```
for ( @cols ){
   # $_ is an arrayref [1,2]
   # you are using it as an index to retrieve a value from @fields
   $line .= $fields[$_];
   # Thus the error: "use of reference ARRAY"..." as array index"
   # You should be using an integer here.
}
```

To fix it:

```
sub setOpts {
   # ...
   @cols = @{ $opts->{columns} };

}
```

Edit: removed unnecessary check